# sql server order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED]
```

It gives me following result:

[image: query result]

The problem is if I am doing `order by MonthCycle` then since it is a string it is using month's first letter to sort, but I want an `order by` on the basis of month like `Jan` should be first, then `Feb` and so on.

Comment: This highlight why you should always use the correct data type.  If at all possible consider switching to the [date data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb630352.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED]
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Jan' then 1
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Feb' then 2
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Mar' then 3
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Apr' then 4
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'May' then 5
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Jun' then 6
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Jul' then 7
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Aug' then 8
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Sep' then 9
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Oct' then 10
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Nov' then 11
  WHEN LEFT(MONTHCYCLE,3) = 'Dec' then 12
  ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a `case` expression that returns the month number:

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED]
order by case left(monthcycle,3) when 'Jan' then 1
                                 when 'Feb' then 2
                                 ...
         end
```

Comment: it wont work coz after all the the monthCycle values are right now in Character string not datetime.
Will it work if i use Convert afetr order by

Comment: That's why I use `left` to pick the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't specify if the report will be spanning several years, but if so I'd use something like this:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 ' + REPLACE(monthCycle, '''', ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `DATEPART`

Something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED] Order by DATEPART(MM,'01'+MONTHCYCLE)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED] Order by DATEPART(MM,'01'+Replace(MONTHCYCLE,'''',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

And another way :)

```
DECLARE @d as date = '2016-01-01'
;WITH months AS (
SELECT  1 as [Month],
        LEFT(DATENAME(Month,@d),3) as MName
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Month] + 1,
        LEFT(DATENAME(Month,DATEADD(Month,[Month],@d)) ,3) 
FROM months 
WHERE [Month] + 1 <= 12
)

SELECT c.*
FROM [TEMPDB].[dbo].[##TEMPMSICHARTFORMATTED] c
LEFT JOIN months m 
    ON c.MONTHCYCLE LIKE m.MName +'%'
ORDER BY RIGHT(c.MONTHCYCLE,2) ASC, m.[Month] ASC
```

Output:

```
MONTHCYCLE TARGET Corp Stnd   Local       OF Stnd
---------- ------ ----------- ----------- -----------
Jan'16            2           1           1
Feb'16            1           1           1
Mar'16            2           3           1
Apr'16            4           3           NULL

(4 row(s) affected)
```